# Add blurb to bottom of each comment section of matlab file in linux

Tags: linux

I feel like there is a sed or awk magic that will do this.

A matlab file is laid out as

```
function [asdfasdf] ...
%comments!
%moar comments! ...
%
%
code
```

I would like to add an additional comment line to the end of each of the comment sections, ie,

1. find the first line after the function line that does not contain a comment
2. Insert the line(s) I want to there

What linux wizardry can do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Save following code to `add_extra_comment.awk`

```
/^[^%]/ {
    if (f) { 
        print "% extra comment";
        f = 0;
    }
}

/^function/ {
    f = 1;
}

{
    print;
}
```

Then run

```
awk -f add_extra_comment.awk < your_matlab_file > modified_matlab_file
```